# Inserting the same footnote at the end of every page automatically

Tags: footnotes

Is there a way to insert say `\footnote{Some text}` at the end of every page automatically without me manually inserting it. If any page contains any other footnote, then this footnote should appear after all of them in that particular page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\footnote{Test 1}\footnote{Test 2}\footnote{Test 3}\footnote{Test 4}\footnote{Test 5}\footnote{Test 6}\footnote{Test 7}\footnote{Test 8}\footnote{Test 9}\footnote{Test 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

For instance, in the above example, `\footnote{Some text}` should appear after `\footnote{Test 10}` on page 1 and by itself at the end of the remaining pages.

Comment: Does the footnote have to be numbered? And if it's on its own, does it need the regular footnote rule?